# Shaky Cross-Cluster Search between 6.5.1 and 5.6.2

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

Here is our context. We had an ES 5.6.2 cluster with 23 nodes (3M + 20D). On that cluster about half of the indices have been created before we migrated to 5.6.2 and the other half after that migration. In order to benefit from newer features and keep the pace with the new releases, we've decided to:

1. split that cluster in two by leaving the older indices (created in ES 2) on the 5.6.2 cluster
2. move the newer indices (created in 5.6) to a new cluster powered by ES 6.5.1
3. and set up [CCS](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-cross-cluster-search.html) unidirectionally between 6.5.1 (new) -> 5.6.2 (old)

The rationale behind this split was that the older indices were way to massive to be reindexed into ES 6.5.1 without interrupting the business. It would have taken weeks. We might still do it at some point, though, but since those indices are going to be [frozen](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/frozen-indices.html) at some point, we didn't see the point of wasting time migrating data that is going to die/freeze anyway.

So, we were pretty confident about moving the newer indices to 6.5.1, and indeed that went pretty smoothly. Shard allocation filtering helped us move all those indices on nodes that were going to be part of the new 6.5.1 cluster. Then, in a rolling migration, we migrated each of those nodes into the new 6.5.1 cluster, which has been green and humming along since then.

The tricky part comes next and you can probably see it coming already. We set up CCS using three seed (data) nodes from the older cluster, and that's when the older cluster started to shake. Aside from [another CCS search bug](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/38889) that we've discovered and filed, the symptoms were that quite frequently a data node would leave and rejoin the cluster, causing an almost constant shard rebalancing.

Put differently, we were left with a yellow cluster that we feared could get red at any time. Occasionally, it would get green again for a few minutes and then back to yellow (and sometimes red for a very brief period of time). See the health history below (the big initial red state to the left was when we moved the new indices over to the new cluster, but all other green/red arrow pairs were temporary red states due to the errors we're going to describe next):

[image]

Concretely, what we're seeing in the logs on the master node of the old 5.6.2 cluster, is that the master would drop the connection to a data node after the following series of events:

First, we see the following error (very similar to [#23939](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/23939)) where we see that a node fails to obtain a lock on a given shard. (Note: We are extensively using scroll search, so that might be a reason as explained in that issue)

```
[2019-02-14T23:53:38,331][WARN ][o.e.c.a.s.ShardStateAction] [IK-PRD-M3] [transactions_2016][1] received shard failed for shard id [[transactions_2016][1]], allocation id [Hy0REX6nScy49_2uXpKqrw], primary term [0], message [failed to create shard], failure [IOException[failed to obtain in-memory shard lock]; nested: ShardLockObtainFailedException[[transactions_2016][1]: obtaining shard lock timed out after 5000ms]; ]
java.io.IOException: failed to obtain in-memory shard lock
at org.elasticsearch.index.IndexService.createShard(IndexService.java:364) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.indices.IndicesService.createShard(IndicesService.java:499) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.indices.IndicesService.createShard(IndicesService.java:147) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.indices.cluster.IndicesClusterStateService.createShard(IndicesClusterStateService.java:542) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.indices.cluster.IndicesClusterStateService.createOrUpdateShards(IndicesClusterStateService.java:519) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.indices.cluster.IndicesClusterStateService.applyClusterState(IndicesClusterStateService.java:204) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterService.callClusterStateAppliers(ClusterService.java:814) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterService.publishAndApplyChanges(ClusterService.java:768) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterService.runTasks(ClusterService.java:587) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterService$ClusterServiceTaskBatcher.run(ClusterService.java:263) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.TaskBatcher.runIfNotProcessed(TaskBatcher.java:150) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.TaskBatcher$BatchedTask.run(TaskBatcher.java:188) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:569) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.runAndClean(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:247) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.run(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:210) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_74]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.env.ShardLockObtainFailedException: [transactions_2016][1]: obtaining shard lock timed out after 5000ms
at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment$InternalShardLock.acquire(NodeEnvironment.java:724) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.shardLock(NodeEnvironment.java:643) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.index.IndexService.createShard(IndexService.java:294) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
... 17 more
```

Right after that, we see a transport-level issue where a message cannot be fully read:

```
[2019-02-14T23:53:52,630][WARN ][o.e.t.n.Netty4Transport  ] [IK-PRD-M3] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0xd97a9d8c, L:/10.10.1.184:51594 - R:10.10.1.166/10.10.1.166:9300]], closing connection
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Message not fully read (response) for requestId [7719647], handler [org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$ContextRestoreResponseHandler/org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportActionProxy$ProxyResponseHandler@7f2fcd88], error [false]; resetting
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.messageReceived(TcpTransport.java:1399) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4MessageChannelHandler.channelRead(Netty4MessageChannelHandler.java:74) ~[transport-netty4-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310) [netty-codec-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:297) [netty-codec-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:413) [netty-codec-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265) [netty-codec-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:134) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:644) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioEventLoop.java:544) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:498) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:458) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858) [netty-common-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_74]
```

And then that data node gets dropped...

`[2019-02-14T23:53:52,639][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterService   ] [IK-PRD-M3] removed {{IK-PRD-D103}{gAwPc0AvTyGR58ugLQ7K4Q}{-MdtgQHlT4SEQsDYTjvRBw}{10.10.1.166}{10.10.1.166:9300}{ml.max_open_jobs=10, ml.enabled=true, tag=hot},}, reason: zen-disco-node-failed({IK-PRD-D103}{gAwPc0AvTyGR58ugLQ7K4Q}{-MdtgQHlT4SEQsDYTjvRBw}{10.10.1.166}{10.10.1.166:9300}{ml.max_open_jobs=10, ml.enabled=true, tag=hot}), reason(transport disconnected)[{IK-PRD-D103}{gAwPc0AvTyGR58ugLQ7K4Q}{-MdtgQHlT4SEQsDYTjvRBw}{10.10.1.166}{10.10.1.166:9300}{ml.max_open_jobs=10, ml.enabled=true, tag=hot} transport disconnected]`

...and readded a few seconds later

`[2019-02-14T23:53:58,367][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterService   ] [IK-PRD-M3] added {{IK-PRD-D103}{gAwPc0AvTyGR58ugLQ7K4Q}{-MdtgQHlT4SEQsDYTjvRBw}{10.10.1.166}{10.10.1.166:9300}{ml.max_open_jobs=10, ml.enabled=true, tag=hot},}, reason: zen-disco-node-join[{IK-PRD-D103}{gAwPc0AvTyGR58ugLQ7K4Q}{-MdtgQHlT4SEQsDYTjvRBw}{10.10.1.166}{10.10.1.166:9300}{ml.max_open_jobs=10, ml.enabled=true, tag=hot}]`

Also worth noting that the nodes that were jumping off and on the cluster were almost always the same three, one of which is in the seed nodes list of the CCS.

Agreed, there's absolutely no clue that CCS has anything to do with this, but since this is pretty much the only change that the old 5.6.2 cluster had undergone and the fact that one of the jumping nodes is a CCS gateway node, the odds are high that CCS is causing this.

One thing that came to mind was to migrate the old 5.6.2 cluster to the latest 5.6.14 patch release, but attempting a migration on an unstable yellow cluster can be risky and that's why we're seeking for advice here.

Looking at the [5.6.3 release notes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/release-notes-5.6.3.html), we see a fix ([#26833](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/26833) fixed by [@javanna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/633239/javanna) in PR [#27881](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/26881)) that might solve our issue, but we're unsure if we need to migrate the whole cluster to 5.6.3 or only the seed nodes. One thing we've attempted was to add two 5.6.3 client nodes (i.e. not master and not data) to the 5.6.2 cluster and use those as seed nodes to CCS, but that made the cluster even more unstable. So we reverted that change, but maybe we didn't do the right thing

We didn't see in any other 5.6. release notes anything that fixed bugs that could cause what we're seeing. We're looking for expert advice on how to solve this, thanks again for your attention.

Note: This has also been posted in the official Elasticsearch forum: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/shaky-cross-cluster-search-between-6-5-1-and-5-6-2/168518/6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrading our 5.6.2 cluster to 5.6.3 indeed fixed the problems.

Our cluster has been green again for the past few hours.

Thanks to the Elastic support team for helping us pinpoint and fix this issue.